# What should 10k users do with flagged answers?

Tags: discussion, flags, 10k-tools

Every once in a while I take a look at the tools page and see a high number of flags - like right now.  And there is indeed some pretty spammy stuff in there.

It's fairly self-evident what to do with flagged *questions*, I think - just vote to close/delete if the flags are in fact accurate.

But what about flagged answers?  It doesn't really seem like there's much we *can* do about those.  Should we:

- Flag them again, hoping to bump the answer down and/or get it auto-deleted?
- Flag for (real) moderator attention, i.e. to confirm "yes this is really spam"?
- Just leave them alone (assuming that a proper mod will find it soon)?

Also - is there any particular action we should be taking if a post is erroneously flagged - i.e. somebody got annoyed that a question wasn't marked CW?

Some guidelines on how best to use this feature would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe just like we are allowed to delete questions, we could be allowed to delete answers too?

Comment: @Kop: I'm betting that such a feature request wouldn't fly.  Questions have to be closed (and stay closed) before deleting, there's no such protection with answers.  I wouldn't want to see unpopular (but not incorrect) answers disappearing due to abuse of a feature like that.

Comment: Agreed. I saw it a couple of time and realizes there isn't much I can do about it. Pretty disappointing...

Comment: I miss the flags view. It was stolen from me by the rep recalc. Sure, I can see flags on Meta, but it's mostly just people hating Evan Carroll.

Comment: Note for future readers: The feature request that @Kop suggested was actually implemented recently, with a few restrictions (three delete votes needed, voters need 20k+ rep each, answer must have score < 0).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to downvote \*and\* vote to delete from the review page as it used to work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364589/282094)   https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228861/282094

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Flag them again, hoping to bump the answer down and/or get it auto-deleted?

I vote for this-- if you see something in the flag list that you feel strongly about, flag it yourself, too. Remember that enough flags (for really bad stuff) cause action to be taken automagically.

> Flag for (real) moderator attention, i.e. to confirm "yes this is really spam"?

This can also work if you have something specific you want to add with a sentence or paragraph of info.

> Just leave them alone (assuming that a proper mod will find it soon)?

As the default, this should *always* work, and if it doesn't, we have built a bad system that needs to be fixed!