# What am I meant to do with flag review

Tags: support, 10k-tools, moderator-abilities

In regards to Flagged Posts tools:

https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged

I can't for the life of me see what I'm meant to do.

All it says is:

> **Where should I start?** Start at the
>   top. This list is ordered by a
>   combination of number (and type) of
>   issues, the reputation of the user who
>   posted, and the flag history and
>   reputation of the flagging user.

Ok so I start at the top, then what?

Comment: May be you can find answer on this post -> [When do I flag, and which flag do I use?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89707/when-do-i-flag-and-which-flag-do-i-use)

Comment: Do people just pick vaguely related questions now and mark as duplicates for fun?  How is this a duplicate?  I thought as a 10k user on SO I got a few more privileges, I'm not asking when I should flag, I'm asking what I should be doing on the flag review page I have access to which seems to indicate I should be doing something.

Comment: Well, first, there is no fun on voting as duplicate. I closed that as duplicate because I think **then what** in your post very close to that.

Comment: Ok I've read the provided link, unfortunately it doesn't answer my question in any way.

Comment: It does answer your question. The part that you're missing is that **what you're supposed to do from that page is determine whether or not you *agree* with the flag**. If you agree, you flag it again. If not, you ignore it and do nothing. The "duplicate" that @YOU proposes attempts to answer the question of "which flags in the list should I agree with, and which should I ignore?"

Answer (score 5):

You can go through those flagged posts and see if there's anything you can do to improve things.  Granted, 10K users don't have a lot of options for dealing with these, but there are some; in particular, you can flag again.  For more, take a look at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44347/what-should-10k-users-do-with-flagged-answers).