# Unable to downvote *and* vote to delete from the review page as it used to work

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, review, low-quality-posts

As you know, trusted users can vote Delete instead of Recommend Deletion for answers with score ≤ 0 ([see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/392799), and ≤ -1 if not from review). Very often, a non-answer gets an upvote (so it has a score of 1), and this [limits trusted users to Recommend Deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029/392799).

What I used to do, to speed things up, is to downvote inside the review page, refresh the page so the option changes to Delete, and then review with that option.

This doesn't seem to work recently. Once refreshed, that review is gone. The second time I closed the review tab, downvoted from the main post page, and went back to the low-quality review queue, and was not presented with that answer.

I found it in the review history, missing the vote score/arrows, but I was able to vote Delete.

I'm thinking that is a bug, not a new feature, because:

1. I could still get to that review from the history

   - Note: I did not find it the first time as I was the first on the scene, that time it also was not in the skipped reviews – assuming a new auto-skip feature
2. Score/arrows become **missing** after downvoting and finding the review again
3. Downvoting and reviewing are not mutually exclusive.

---

If needed for troubleshooting, this is the second review where this happened: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/57850

Comment: Would be nice if voting, or potentially a score change detection, caused a recalculation of the review actions available to you instead of requiring a refresh. Alas, this is still problematic.

Comment: FWIW 20K users can not vote delete answers with score zero, only those that are negative score. I just verified this at the site where I have 20K

Comment: @gnat: from the review queue it's 0, from the answer itself it needs -1 (I added a link).

Comment: now that you mention it, you re probably right, I vaguely recall something like that per my own experience in LQ queue. Anyway, when answer is just one vote away from turning from recommendation to vote my approach is to vote it outside of the queue in a different browser tab then returning to review tab and clicking recommend deletion. If memory serves at this moment system picks the updated post score and turns my action into vote

Comment: @gnat: Thanks for the tip. I'll test it whenever there's a similar item in the LQ queue and will update the post here. But certainly something has changed, and it's now un-user-friendly IMO.

Comment: There was a [post in the Low Quality queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/78217) where I was able to leave the queue and flag it as spam (for self promotion), that caused a downvote, then I was able to back button navigate to the VLQ and also recommend deletion - kind of a double vote / flag.

Comment: @ymb1 Are you still seeing this behavior on LQ reviews? I am trying to reproduce it and I so far haven't managed it. If I downvote a post in the LQ queue, I can refresh the page with no issues and I still see the voting controls. The post doesn't show up in my review history (which makes sense, I haven't taken a review action) but does show up in my voting history (also as expected). Am I missing a step or did we already fix this somewhere along the way?

Comment: @AdamLear: I haven't reviewed LQ at all since late May, and right now no items with score 1 are in the LQ queue where I'm a Trusted user, but I'll keep an eye on the queue, test, and I'll be sure to let you know right away. Thanks for the follow-up.

Comment: @AdamLear: It's not fixed. LQ has been quiet, but finally there was an item with 0 score. To test I upvoted from the review page, and refreshed, and the review actions were gone, which is the same behavior as if it had been 1, downvoted, and refreshed to change *Recommend Deletion* to *Delete* (review actions gone). [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHkoP.png)

Comment: @AdamLear: Sorry, I think the upvote invalidates the LQ? I'll have to wait for an already 1 score LQ item to downvote and test.

Comment: @AdamLear: you probably thought I forgot, I didn't! Finally a score 1 that needed a delete vote came my way: DV'ed, refreshed, and it worked fine ([link](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/60067)) ;)

Comment: @ymb1 Glad to hear it, thanks for confirming :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed at some point already:

> [image: A GIF shows a downvote on a 1-scored post in the queue, then the page is reloaded, and the "Recommend deletion" action changes to "Delete"]

If you see any other (or this one again :)) issues in the queues, please don't hesitate to report them again.